# Editable Tree View for MVC using jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-2, treeview

I'm looking for an Editable tree view which easily lets me to make new items, rename and delete them.

before i started using MVC i used the Obout tree which works quite well: http://www.obout.com/t_db/index.aspx

but this isnt going to run in jQuery, so i'd like to know if someone has some experience in a jQuery solution. i guess i'll build a  element as the tree from the DB. I will use 3 lvls of depth as a maximum. Could be nice if the tree will have a Sortable option like the jQuery UI: http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/

Does anyone have an idea of a good jQuery plugin which might come close to doing the job?

thanks in advance.
Stefan

Answer (score 3):

I've found [jsTree](http://www.jstree.com/) to be a pretty nice tree control.  Maybe it will work for you?

Comment: @Stefanvds: There is a brand new version of jsTree that just came out with lots of great features. I'm currently using the previous version, and it did everything that you mention you need. I'm sure the new version can do all of that and more. I hope it works for you.